# How to find the document near _id in mongodb, mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Example : I have the documents below:

```
_id = 1, _id = 2, _id = 3, _id = 4, _id = 5, _id = 6, _id = 7, _id = 8, _id = 9
```

In MySQL I use the `ABS` absolute value function:

```
ORDER BY ABS(_id - 1) ASC
LIMIT 3

Then result is [_id = 1, _id = 2, _id = 3]
```

If I use:

```
ORDER BY ABS(_id - 5) ASC
LIMIT 3
Then result is [_id = 4, _id = 5, _id = 6]
```

How can I achieve this in mongoose?

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB doesn't provide an absolute value operator, but you can still do this using an aggregation pipeline that uses [`$let`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/#exp._S_let) to perform the `_id - 5` subtraction and [`$cond`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond) to compute the absolute value.

```js
Test.aggregate([
    {$project: {
        abs_id: {
            $let: {
                vars: {sub_id: { $subtract: ['$_id', 5] }},
                in: {
                    $cond: {
                        if: { $lt: ['$$sub_id', 0] },
                        then: { $multiply: [-1, '$$sub_id'] },
                        else: '$$sub_id'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        doc: '$$ROOT',
        _id: 0
    }},
    {$sort: {abs_id: 1}},
    {$limit: 5}
],
function(err, results) {...});
```

So this projects a `abs_id` field along with the original document as the `doc` field. You can transform `results` back into a simple array of documents using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
var docs = results.map(function(item) { return item.doc; });
```

Comment: I using mongoose, how to convert it :)

Comment: @user3129040 This is using Mongoose; replace `Test` with whatever Mongoose model you're using. Note that some of the aggregation operators do require MongoDB 2.6 or later.

Comment: I will try succes, but results repeated 3 times.

Comment: @user3129040 Sorry, I don't understand your comment.

Comment: thanks u for reply, I mind is _id it repeat 3 time in one run code.. E/x: results is {[_id:1,_id:2,_id:3],[_id:1,_id:2,_id:3],[_id:1,_id:2,_id:3]}

Answer (score 1):

1- Finds the documents near _id: 5, and suppose that we already get the handler for Test (Any Collection - You used) Collection.

```
Test.find({_id: {$gte: 5 } }, function(errs, data) {

    // Your code inside callback function.

});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, if array _id is [1,4,6,9,10,15,16,20] and I want to get the documents nearest _id = 10.. so what?

Comment: // Great by using $elemMatch operator to match the _id elements that are equal 5 and greater than it.

Test.find({_id: { $elemMatch : { $gte: 5 } } }, function(errs, data) {

    // Your code inside callback function.

});

// Good Luck